# Error PHP loop on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

While mixing the loop I got the following errors

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\world\wp-content\themes\world-changing\index.php on line 116

here's my index.php file:

```
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="showcase-content">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Speech Language and Therapy</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim   </p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More &rarr;</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Speech Language and Therapy</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim   </p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More &rarr;</a>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Speech Language and Therapy</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  </p>
                            <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More &rarr;</a>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="showcase-content">
                        <ul>
                        <li>
                            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                             <figure> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'opacity-hover box-layer img-responsive')); ?></a> </figure>
                             <p class="excerpt"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>

                            <div>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more">Read More &rarr;</a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: your codes inside the question is cut, where is the closing of `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>` --> `<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: @Ghost, that's what's causing the error.

Comment: @TomásCot yes maybe it is, or maybe what the OP did is just pasted a part of the question and accidentally truncated the ending, still hasn't responded yet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you:

a. Didn't close the if statement checking for the post_thumbnail
b. Placed the closing loop statements in the wrong order at the end of the document. The while loop should close before the if statement.

Try this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="showcase-content">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                         <figure> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'opacity-hover box-layer img-responsive')); ?></a> </figure>
                        <?php } ?>
                         <p class="excerpt"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>

                        <div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more">Read More &rarr;</a>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>


                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```